# Question about sylow p-subgroup and Proof that $G$ is not simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group and let primes $p$ and $q$ ($p\neq q$), where $q$ divides order of $G$. Prove that if $G$ has precisely one proper sylow $p$-subgroup, it is a normal and therefore $G$ is not simple.

Let $H$ be sylow $p$-subgroup.

Since conjugate of $H$ is also sylow $p$-subgroup and there is only one sylow $p$-subgroup,

It must be that $gH=Hg$ for $g\in G$. Since $H$ is proper sylow-$p$ subgroup, $H$ is not equal to $G$ and identity. Therefore $G$ is not simple.

However, I do not use any conditions given in "Let $G$ be a finite group and let primes $p$ and $q$ ($p\neq q$), where $q$ divides order of $G$."

Why am I given such statement and do I necessarily need it to prove that $G$ is not simple?

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is not finite, then I do not think that maximal p-subgroups (I reserve the term sylow p-subgroup for the finite case) are conjugate to each other.  Thus your proof fails. Also although technically, in this situation you don't need the second condition (a second prime divisor of $|G|$), this condition is what guarantees the existence of any proper sylow p-subgroups at all (since the sylow p-subgroup of a p-group is the group itself).

Comment: Can the second condition be used to deduce that H is not same as G?

Comment: Yes. The order of our sylow p-subgroup is $p^n$ for some $n$, and the order of the larger group is $p^{n}m$ for some $m$ not divided by $p$. Clearly these can not be equal.

Comment: But, it seems like the fact that H is not equal to G naturally follows from having proper sylow-p subgroup. Weird..

Comment: It does.  That is the definition of "proper".  That is why technically that isn't a needed condition.

Comment: Thank you! your explanation helped me a lot!